# Failed to serialize Entity Framework class webapi

Tags: c#, xml, entity-framework, serialization, asp.net-web-api

I was searching for this issues but haven't found what I need. I need to use Entity Framework model in Web API for getting XML requests and responses.

I have two classes with a one-to-many relationship:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract(Name = "shepherd")]
[KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(Sheep))]
public partial class Shepherd
{
        public Shepherd()
        {
            this.Sheep = new HashSet<Sheep>();
        }

        [DataMember(Name = "shepherdId")]
        //[XmlElement("shepherdId")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "name")]
        //[XmlElement("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "isDeleted")]
        //[XmlElement("IsDeleted")]
        public Nullable<bool> IsDeleted { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "sheeps")]
        //[XmlArray("sheeps"), XmlArrayItem("sheep")]
        public virtual ICollection<Sheep> Sheep { get; set; }
    }
```

and this is the second class:

```
[DataContract(Name = "sheep")]
[KnownType(typeof(Shepherd))]
public partial class Sheep
{
        [DataMember(Name = "id")]
        //[XmlElement("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "colour")]
        // [XmlElement("colour")]
        public string Colour { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "createdon")]
        //[XmlElement("CreatedOn")]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public int Shepherd { get; set; }
        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public virtual Shepherd Shepherd1 { get; set; }
}
```

and I always get this error:

> The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.
>   System.InvalidOperationException
>
> Type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Shepherd_EF797FA5FAF7ACF0AF313B6DFF83AF6E5F2EE1AD57BC457F9C10E73BA5DEEFE6' with data contract name 'Shepherd_EF797FA5FAF7ACF0AF313B6DFF83AF6E5F2EE1AD57BC457F9C10E73BA5DEEFE6:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.

I need to get only XML not Json

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee705457(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Which class you are serializing Sheep or Shepherd, or any other class that is in turn using these two ?

Comment: @NoNameR: my bad, that article is about wcf while you are on web api. Try to turn off proxies as described here http://codeglee.com/2014/07/20/serializationexception-when-using-entityframework-pocos-in-webapi/ Note that with this approach you don't have lazy loads so you have to manually control the depth of the tree by "including" dependand entities to queries. Yet another, much cleaner approach would be to switch to DTO entites.

Comment: @NoNameR You have to disable proxy creation in `DbContext.Configuration` or create a 'true' POCO and map to it instead.